# Select only the row with the max value, but the column with this info is a SUM()

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CAB.CODPARC, 
PAR.RAZAOSOCIAL, 
BAI.NOMEBAI,
SUM(VLRNOTA) AS AMOUNT

FROM TGFCAB CAB, TGFPAR PAR, TSIBAI BAI

WHERE CAB.CODPARC = PAR.CODPARC
AND PAR.CODBAI = BAI.CODBAI
AND CAB.TIPMOV = 'V'
AND STATUSNOTA = 'L'
AND PAR.CODCID = 5358

GROUP BY 
CAB.CODPARC, 
PAR.RAZAOSOCIAL, 
BAI.NOMEBAI
```

Which the result is this. Company names and neighborhood hid for obvious reasons

[image]

The query at the moment, for those who don't understand Latin languages, is giving me clients, company name, company neighborhood, and the total value of movements.

in the WHERE clause it is only filtering sales movements of companies from an established city.

But if you notice in the Select statement, the column that is retuning the value that aggregates the total amount of value of sales is a SUM().

My goal is to return only the company that have the maximum value of this column, if its a tie, display both of em.

This is where i'm struggling, cause i can't seem to find a simple solution. I tried to use

```
WHERE AMOUNT = MAX(AMOUNT)
```

But as expected it didn't work

Comment: I've removed all the conflicting tags here. MySQL <> SQL Server and PL/SQL is this SQL dialect Oracle uses. Please tag properly.

Comment: Also, it's 2021! It long past time you adopted the explicit ANSI-92 JOIN syntax; it *has* been around for almost 30 years now.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: And decide for **exactly one** DBMS this question should be about.

Comment: sticky bit, i tagged properly, i use both Microsoft SQL and PLSQL. But Ill leave it then.

Comment: @pegorari: No, you did not tag properly. A question should be about one DBMS. (Unless in very rare cases where really two DBMS are involved *simultaneously* in *one* problem, say because of a distributed query). If you have a similar problem on two DBMS that's two questions. But make sure both questions meet the quality standard (this one doesn't even nearly do) and maybe leave a hint in the questions that mention the coexistence of each other and that they aren't duplicates because of targeting different systems.

Comment: @pegorari: A general goal of communication on this site is to be precise and focused (Hence just one DBMS for one question) and no-frills, no-small-talk. Some people may perceive that as rude or something. You maybe one of them. But it isn't meant like that, it's just a tool to achieve the overall quality and usefulness of the information stored here. And you should remember, if someone criticizes your code or your post, they criticize exactly **that** and ***not*** you as a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with the whole bunch of different databases; do you really use all of them?

Because, "PL/SQL" reads as "Oracle". If that's so, here's one option.

```
with temp as
  -- this is your current query
  (select columns,
          sum(vrlnota) as amount
   from ...
   where ...
  )
-- query that returns what you asked for  
select *
from temp t
where t.amount = (select max(a.amount)
                  from temp a
                 );
```

Comment: Oracle and Microsoft SQL. Will try to

Comment: It worked on PL/SQL. I wonder if there is a easier way using subqueries. Cause IDK if this can work on Microsoft Server SQL too. Because here in my company we work on both databases.

Comment: This *is* an easier way. MS SQL Server supports the WITH factoring clause; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: yes. the same query worked for both Oracle PL/SQL and Microsoft SQL Server. The only thing different was the City Code for the differente Databases.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the same without the need for a subquery using `window over()` function,

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT
  CAB.CODPARC, 
  PAR.RAZAOSOCIAL, 
  BAI.NOMEBAI,
  SUM(VLRNOTA) AS AMOUNT,
  MAX(VLRNOTA) over() AS MAMOUNT
  FROM TGFCAB CAB
  JOIN TGFPAR PAR ON PAR.CODPARC = CAB.CODPARC
  JOIN TSIBAI BAI ON BAI.CODBAI = PAR.CODBAI
  WHERE CAB.TIPMOV = 'V'
    AND STATUSNOTA = 'L'
    AND PAR.CODCID = 5358
  GROUP BY CAB.CODPARC, PAR.RAZAOSOCIAL, BAI.NOMEBAI
)
SELECT CODPARC, RAZAOSOCIAL, NOMEBAI, AMOUNT
FROM T
WHERE AMOUNT=MAMOUNT
```

Note it's usually (always) beneficial to join tables using clear explicit `join` syntax. This should be fine cross-platform between Oracle & SQL Server.